# What's the map from any linear classical codes to entanglement-assisted stabilizers codes

Tags: entanglement, linear-algebra, stabilizer-code, fault-tolerance, cq-states

When a linear code is self-dual, its parity check matrix can be used to easily define a stabilizer code.

From my understanding, thanks to entanglement-assisted stabilizer codes, it is possible to apply such method to any linear code (not necessarily self-dual).

I'm struggling to find those steps to show how such maps applies.

Most of references base their math on encoding-decoding criteria. However, I'm not interested in such kind of protocols where decoding occurs, as I am more interested to understand this in fault-tolerant computing.

I would appreciate an explanation on how to use such an entanglement advantage, to define a code, starting from any linear code.